# How to achieve effect where small view becomes full screen view? Similar to Snapchat transition from collection-view to content view

Tags: ios, swift

I included a GIF to better show what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

**How can I achieve this?**

Some Ideas:

- Possibly make a collection view of containerView's?
- Or maybe use views? (this seems easiest but i need to be able to include a containerView inside of the full Content view)

**Note:** I need to create this sort of functionality in only one spot so if I were to use a collectionView It would always have only 1 Cell.

Also, Another example and probably a better one of what I would like to achieve is the apple photos app. In it, you have a collection view of images and when you tap one it expands to a full screen but as a VC. I would also like to achieve the kind of free feel you get when swiping down in photos app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it with a cell of a collection view.

[image]

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  test
//
//  Created by Sergio Rodríguez Rama on 22/04/2019.
//  Copyright © 2019 Sergio Rodríguez Rama. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    private var smallView: UIView?
    private var smallFrame: CGRect?
    private var bigFrame: CGRect?

    @objc private func viewTapped() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: { [weak self] in
            guard let smallFrame = self?.smallFrame else { return }
            self?.smallView?.frame = smallFrame
        }) { [weak self] _ in
            self?.smallView?.removeFromSuperview()
            self?.collectionView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        bigFrame = view.frame
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath)
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) else { return }
        smallFrame = collectionView.convert(cell.frame, to: view)
        smallView = cell.copyView()
        guard let smallFrame = smallFrame, let smallView = smallView else { return }
        smallView.frame = smallFrame
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(viewTapped))
        smallView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
        view.addSubview(smallView)
        collectionView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: { [weak self] in
            guard let frame = self?.bigFrame else { return }
            self?.smallView?.frame = frame
        })
    }
}

extension UIView
{
    func copyView<T: UIView>() -> T {
        return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self)) as! T
    }
}
```